# See JavaScript variable's value in Codeception Acceptance test

Tags: javascript, php, variables, xmlhttprequest, codeception

Is there any way to see vanilla JavaScript variable's value while running acceptance test?

PHP variable's value can be seen in debug using $I->seeMyVar($var), but how to pass JS variable's value to PHP variable?

I tried this, but it sends empty array instead:

```
<script>
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://URLHERE?varId="+varId, true);
xmlHttp.addEventListener("load", ajaxCallback, false);
xmlHttp.send();

function ajaxCallback(event){
    alert( "loaded");
}
</script>

<?php
```

And then this in function's body:

```
    $varId = $_GET;
    $I->seeMyVar($varId);
```

Comment: Did you try to do return in your JS. And then save it to PHP $var. Like $var = $I->executeJS(return jsvar); And then do $I->seeMyVar($var);

Comment: Have you find a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

If your page has some javascript like the following which defines `SOME_VARIABLE`

```html
<script>
    SOME_VARIABLE='hello';
</script>
```

You can grab it in codeception and use it in PHP by doing the following

```php
$someVariable = $I->executeJS('return SOME_VARIABLE');
```